# How do you get event details in GWTQuery?

Tags: gwtquery

I'm trying to create a program where I need to fire events whenever the text in a text box is changed. Here's the code written for it:

```
$("#text_box").change(new Function(){
        public void f(){
            ....
        }
    });
```

But I need to get the details of the event - such as - the character that was entered. There is no object passed through the GQuery API to send that information.How can I get these details?

Answer (score 0):

Just override the method f(Event e)

```
$("#text_box").change(new Function(){

    public void f(Event e){
        ....
    }
});
```